# 403 error code Google Drive Python The download quota for this file has been exceeded

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I used Google Drive Python library https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

```
try:
    request = self.api.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as local_fd:
        media_request = http.MediaIoBaseDownload(local_fd, request, chunksize=Constant.CHUNK_SIZE)
        done = False
        while not done:
            download_progress, done = media_request.next_chunk(num_retries=Constant.MAXRETRY_NUM)
            if download_progress:
                logger.debug('Sleep 5 Download Progress: %d%%' % int(download_progress.progress() * 100))
            sleep(5)
except Exception, exp:
    return self.__exp_handler(exp)
```

and received 403 error when download large file

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "quota.download"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded"
 }
}
```

It always happens after 53 request download regardless of chunk size.

I do not see any error in the handler error.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2016-08-12**: This issue should now be resolved.

This appears to be a bug in how we calculate download quota, since chunked downloads should only count as one download. The engineering team is aware of the problem, and if file an issue on our tracker I can update when we know more:

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/

Comment: I still do not understand the reason. Even wrong calculation but how to exceed the quota with "requests/day  0 of 1,000,000,000  
requests/100seconds/user  1,000" - limitation from my application

Comment: The Google Drive API enforces additional, undocumented quotas in order to protected our backends from abuse. Unfortunately the exact details on these additional quotas cannot be made public.

Comment: We've pushed out a fix that we believe should resolve this issue. Let us know if you still see the problem.

Comment: @EricKoleda is `downloadQuotaExceeded` one of the quotas that cannot be made public? I couldn't find any information regarding `403 Forbidden` errors with that text as the `reason`. Thanks!