# Google Drive api "The download quota for this file has been exceeded"

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am working on an app that uploads and downloads files from Google Drive. I have the upload/download mechanisms in place, and have been doing some download tests using a couple files that have been uploaded. All was well about 13 hours ago. However, now, I just tried to download one of these files again, and I get a "403" error indicating that "The download quota for this file has been exceeded"

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "downloadQuotaExceeded",
    "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded."
 }
}
```

I've downloaded this file maybe 10 or 20 times yesterday while debugging and doing some testing with other parts of the app. 10 or 20 seems like a very low threshhold to start throttling downloads. Obviously, I could just upload a new file and start downloading it instead. So this seems very odd. Has anyone else had to deal with this error from the Google Drive api? My code that is doing the download is very simple and is shown below:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636371/403-error-code-google-drive-python-the-download-quota-for-this-file-has-been-exc  Note the comment "The Google Drive API enforces additional, undocumented quotas in order to protected our backends from abuse. Unfortunately the exact details on these additional quotas cannot be made public"

Comment: You can check your quota usage at: [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: were you able to find any information regarding `downloadQuotaExceeded`?

Answer (score -1):

You have the link, for example:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE ID]?alt=media&key=[ETC...]

Take the [FILE ID], add paste it to the GDrive link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=[FILE ID]

Now you have access to the file.

Then create a copy to your own Drive folder, so you can download the file and avoid the "downloadQuotaExceeded" message.